# How to prove this statement on finite groups?

Tags: representation-theory

I [Fulton and Harris Chapter 3.2](http://books.google.de/books/about/Representation_Theory.html?id=6GUH8ARxhp8C&redir_esc=y) we have that if $\mathbb{C}^n$ is the permutation representation of $S_n$ (symmetric group) then we can write $\mathbb{C}^n=V\oplus U$, where $U$ is the trivial representation and $V$ is the standard representation. Then they claim that $V$ is irreducible iff $(\chi_{\mathbb{C}^n},\chi_{\mathbb{C}^n})=2$, but I can't see the left direction.

What I see is:

$$2=(\chi_{\mathbb{C}^n},\chi_{\mathbb{C}^n})=(\chi_{V}+\chi_U,\chi_{V}+\chi_U)=
(\chi_{V},\chi_V)+2(\chi_{V},\chi_U)+(\chi_{U},\chi_U)=
(\chi_{V},\chi_V)+2(\chi_{V},\chi_U)+1$$

since $U$ is irreducible, so we have $(\chi_{V},\chi_V)+2(\chi_{V},\chi_U)=1$, but how can we now imply the irreducibility of $V$, i.e. $(\chi_{V},\chi_V)=1$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show $(\chi_V,\chi_U)=0$? What would it mean if $(\chi_V,\chi_U)\neq 0$?

Comment: I know it should be since they are both irreducible but before knowing this I can't show it.

Comment: But you don't need $\chi_V$ to be irreducible for $(\chi_V,\chi_U)=0$. Since $U$ is irreducible, you only need to show that$\chi_V$ cannot have a sub-representation isomorphic to $\chi_U$.

Comment: I suppose this goes from Schur's lemma, I mean your last statement?

Comment: So it has been a long time since I've read representation theory, but my memory is that if $(\chi_U,\chi_V)\neq 0$ then $U$ and $V$ have to have non-zero sub-representations which are isomorphic. Since $U$ is irreducible, that would mean that there would have to be a sub-representation of $V$ isomorphic to $U$.

Comment: Yes, actually you are right. I found it in the book: The multiplicity $a_i$ of $V_i$ in $V$ is the inner product of $\chi_V$ with $\chi_{V_i}$, i.e. $a_i=(\chi_V,\chi_{V_i})$. It would be contradiction if they had common subrepresentation, I mean $U$ and $V$ in my question. You can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if $U$ is irreducible, then $(U,V)\neq 0$ implies that $U$ is a sub-representation of $V$.

So you need only prove that $U$ is not a sub-representation of $V$ in this case - that is, there is no subspace of $V$ on which the action of $G$ is a constant.